# What does te form of verbs mean in these two sentences?

Tags: grammar, translation, verbs, て-form, punctuation

> 犬は雪の中を走ってボールを取りに行く。
>
> 時間がありまして、映画を見ました。

Are the grammar in these two the same? If yes, why is there a comma in the second one and not in the first one?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, they are the same. The て-form is used in both cases to connect multiple actions together (often sequentially in time). You can think of it as the English `and`.

In Japanese, the comma can be used basically whenever one wants to indicate a break in thought. It is also fairly optional. That is to say, there's no real difference in using a comma or not here. It's an optional separator.