# Why is the volitional form used here?

Tags: grammar, word-choice, verbs

> このアカウントをフォローして、写真や動画をチェックしよう。

Why was しよう used instead of して？

I was thinking して because it appears to be a request.

Comment: If you explain why you expected して it will be easier to address what you're struggling with.

Comment: okay, i edited my question!

Comment: Just to clarify, is it because して comes first, which you're interpreting as a request, and then from that perspective しよう appears to not align with it?

Comment: @Leebo yeah, i think that is why. if not a request what would it translate to?

Comment: In that case, it might be that questions about the て form as a conjunction would cover what you want to know. I found this one, but there might be other better ones. https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/64464/what-does-te-form-of-verbs-mean-in-these-two-sentences/64484?r=SearchResults#64484

Comment: @Leebo what i really want to know is the meaning of しよう since it’s in the volitional form here :))

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the translation, plainly and without any other context, is:

> このアカウントをフォローして、写真や動画をチェックしよう。
>
> Let’s follow this account and (then) check the photos and videos.

The volitional form used on its own has the meaning of “let’s”, and applies to the whole phrase. The earlier して is acting connectively.

して mid-sentence cannot, to my knowledge, be used as a contraction for してください, because the (much) more common use of して is the connective form.

Comment: thank you! it was on instagram for someone’s private account (i switched my app language to japanese)

Comment: No worries! Glad to have helped.